# What should i add to my site to make google index the subpages as well

Tags: indexing, googlebot

I am a beginner web developer and i have a site [JammuLinks.com](http://www.jammulinks.com), it is built on php. It is a city local listing search engine. Basically i've written search pages which take in a parameter, fetch the records from the database and display it. So it is dynamically generating the content. However if you look at the bottom of the site, i have added many static links where i have hard coded the parameters in the link like searchresult.php?tablename='schools'. So my question is

Since google crawls the page and also the links listed in the page, will it be crawling the results page data as well? How can i identify if it has. So far i tried site:www.jammulinks.com but it results the homepage and the blog alone.

What more can i add to make the static links be indexed by it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create a sitemap document (you can even get the template from Google's webmaster portion of their sites, www.google.com/webmasters/ I believe).

Comment: The scenario is this, it is a listing site, so there are 2000+ listings which i want to be indexed. Is there any restriction if i do so?

Comment: There should not be. I have even used this approach and had the file auto-generated with top areas or all inclusive.